# CANVAS clear the drawing board in a loop(requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

i am trying to do interactive stuff in a canvas using requestAnimationFrame. Problem, i'm stuck with, is the functoin to clear and make a 'blank' canvas space seems not working in loop. as previous tests my code below could look incomplete or not the better one that's because that's base tries to do better(OOP and MV+).
I can move my 'test square' a basic shape but old drawing still is on screen.
In a basic HTML such:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test jeu action</title>
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
body{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#000;overflow:hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>/* i separate it for easier view on forum see further*/
</script></body></html>
```

I've the JS below:

```js
/** global fn as tools */
function isReal(v){return v!='undefined' && v!=null ? true:false; }

/** animation loop */
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
function animate(){
 if(ctrls.input.states.up==true){rc.y-=moveSpeed;}
 if(ctrls.input.states.down==true){rc.y+=moveSpeed;}
 if(ctrls.input.states.left==true){rc.x-=moveSpeed;}
 if(ctrls.input.states.right==true){rc.x+=moveSpeed;}
 cnv.ctx.fillStyle = '#c0ffc0';
 cnv.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.w, cnv.h);//-- fill BG/clear canvas drawing 
 drawRect(cnv.ctx, rc.x,rc.y,rc.w,rc.h,'#ff0000', '#0000ff');
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
/** graphic as sketching Canvas 2d */
function addCanvas(id,ancestor,w,h){
 let c=document.createElement('canvas');
    c.id=id;
 c.setAttribute('WIDTH', w);
 c.setAttribute('HEIGHT', h);
 ancestor.appendChild(c);
 return {tag:c, ctx:c.getContext('2d'), w:w, h:h};/*-- suppose that CANVAS and CanvasRendere2d are supported in running script environment , todo: add real CANVAS test + polyfil*/
}

function drawRect(ctx,x, y, w, h, stk='#ffffff', fll='#ffffff'){//-- set stk or fll to false(or null) to set drawing options
 if(typeof ctx== typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d')){
  ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
  if(isReal(stk) && stk!=false){
   ctx.strokeStyle=stk;
   ctx.stroke();
   console.log('drawRect stroke '+x+','+y+','+w+','+h+' '+stk);
  }
  if(isReal(fll) && fll!=false){
   ctx.fillStyle=fll;
   ctx.fill();
   console.log('drawRect fill '+x+','+y+','+w+','+h+' '+fll);

  }
  
  return ctx;
 }
 console.log('WRONG Drawing Context: '+ctx+' must be CanvasRenderer2D');
 return;
}


let cnv=addCanvas('cnv',document.body, window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight );
console.log('window canvas size: '+cnv.w+'X'+cnv.h);
function testItem(){let tmp=Math.round(cnv.w/50);return {w:tmp, h:tmp, x:tmp,y:tmp}}
let rc=testItem();
console.log('('+rc.x+' '+rc.y+')');


/** INPUTs MANAGEMENT : Controls (keyboard) */
function Controls(id){
return{
 id:id,
 input:{
  states:{},
  keys:{
   up:38,
   down:40,
   right:39,
   left:37
   }
  }
 }
}

let moveSpeed=2;
let ctrls = Controls('controler');
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
 switch(e.keyCode){
  case ctrls.input.keys.up:
   ctrls.input.states['up']=true;
  break;
  case ctrls.input.keys.right:
   ctrls.input.states['right']=true;
  break;
  case ctrls.input.keys.down:
   ctrls.input.states['down']=true;
  break;
  case ctrls.input.keys.left:
   ctrls.input.states['left']=true;
  break;
  default:/* no assigned control, do nothing*/;
  break;
 }
 console.log('states\n up:'+ctrls.input.states.up+'\t right:'+ctrls.input.states.right+'\t down:'+ctrls.input.states.down+'\t left:'+ctrls.input.states.left);
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
 switch(e.keyCode){
  case ctrls.input.keys.up:if(isReal(ctrls.input.states['up'])){ctrls.input.states.up=false;}
  break;
  case ctrls.input.keys.right:if(isReal(ctrls.input.states['right'])){ctrls.input.states.right=false;}
  break;
  case ctrls.input.keys.down:if(isReal(ctrls.input.states['down'])){ctrls.input.states.down=false;}
  break;
  case ctrls.input.keys.left:if(isReal(ctrls.input.states['left'])){ctrls.input.states.left=false;}
  break;

  default:;break;
 }
});

let anim=animate();
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#000;overflow:hidden;}
```

I've tried with .save() .restore() (on the 1st draw) that won't change anything and .beginPath() .closePath() on the shape drawing and for that draw change but not the way i need it.
Thanks for your clues, i did not see what's the problem...

Comment: At the beginning of the function `drawRect` add `ctx.beginPath()`

Comment: Nice it's work fine thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the context via a hack (using it's canvas):

```
canvas.width = canvas.width
```

Comment: that wasn't the problem... this not the context i wanna clear but the drawing ;) thank anyway for trying to answer.